# Delphi 7 .DFM file display error

Tags: delphi, dfm

I have to maintain an Delphi 7 application.
I've received the source code of this app, and when I try to open .DFM file or .DCU file by Notepad++,  some of them display normaly with the source code, but some of them display incorrect with strange characters.
How can I recover these file
I will appreciate your help

[image]

Comment: *"I have to maintain an Delphi 7 application", "I don't install Delphi 7 because it's not free", "I installed Delphi 7"*  You are not making a lot of sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the .DFM, you can either:

- Open the file in the IDE, right-click the form, and check `Text DFM` and then save it, or
- From a command prompt in the folder where the `.dfm` is located, run `convert <dfmfile.dfm>`, which will convert it to text format with the same name. (`Convert.exe` is located in your `$(DELPHI)\Bin` folder, where `$(DELPHI)` refers to the root folder of your Delphi 7 installation).

The `.dcu` is compiled (binary) code, so to view it you need to open the `.pas` file with the same name (eg., if you have `Unit1.dcu`, you view it's source by opening `Unit1.pas`). There's no way to view the `.dcu` as text, because it isn't text.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now I don't install Delphi 7 because it's not free:( Is there another way to open DFM file without Delphi 7 (with Notepad++ or Lazarus)?

Comment: If you have to maintain a Delphi 7 application, you need Delphi. You can't edit a binary .DFM file with Notepad++. I don't know if Lazarus includes a utility similar to convert, but that isn't the question you asked here. (You didn't mention Lazarus at all, as a matter of fact.) I also don't know if one of the Delphi trial versions will work for converting the .DFM files, because I've never tried them. Expect to run into major problems without having Delphi if the project contains third party components as well; many of them don't work in Lazarus/FPC.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I installed Delphi 7 and open .DFM file properly.